# Chanun V'Rachum vs. Rachum V'Chanun

Tags: words, tachanun

In the long tachanun of Monday and Thursday (among other places) there is repeated use of Chanun V'Rachum (a phrase which appears in Nach 8 or so times)

אֵל טוב וְסַלָּח כִּי אֵל מֶלֶךְ **חַנוּן וְרַחוּם** אָתָּה:
אָנָּא מֶלֶךְ **חַנּוּן וְרַחוּם**. זְכר וְהַבֵּט לִבְרִית בֵּין הַבְּתָרִים וְתֵרָאֶה לְפָנֶיךָ עֲקֵדַת יָחִיד לְמַעַן יִשרָאֵל. אָבִינוּ מַלְכֵּנוּ חָנֵּנוּ וַעֲנֵנוּ. כִּי שִׁמְךָ הַגָּדול נִקְרָא עָלֵינוּ. עשה נִפְלָאות בְּכָל עֵת. עֲשה עִמָּנוּ כְּחַסְדֶּךָ. **חַנּוּן וְרַחוּם**

In two cases, though, the text flips the two terms (into a form found in Tanach 3 times)

אֵל **רַחוּם וְחַנּוּן**, רַחֵם עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל מַעֲשיךָ

**רַחוּם וְחַנּוּן** חָטָאתִי לְפָנֶיךָ

Is there any difference in meaning that would impact the particular phrases or explain the choice to use one over the other? Is the construction only stylistic or is it meaningful?

[text from [sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Post_Amidah%2C_Tachanun%2C_Shomer_Yisrael.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), Ashkenazic siddur)